How to configure AWS Lightsail IPv6-only instance to use NAT64?
I have Ubuntu 22 running on AWS Lightsail IPv6-only instance. I can connect from that instance to IPv6 servers just fine. However connecting to IPv4 fails:
ping wordpress.org
PING wordpress.org (198.143.164.252) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- wordpress.org ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4092ms

There is a free NAT64 service at https://nat64.net/ that should allow connecting to IPv4 servers.
How do I configure my instance to use their nameservers?
I believe Lightsail instances receive IP configuration from DHCP server so ideally the instance should receive IP address from DHCP and override DNS settings somehow.

Open /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml in editor and add these lines:
        dhcp4-overrides:
            use-dns: false
        dhcp6-overrides:
            use-dns: false
        nameservers:
            addresses: ["2a01:4f8:c2c:123f::1","2a00:1098:2c::1","2a01:4f9:c010:3f02::1"]

Then execute:
sudo netplan generate

sudo netplan apply

See https://netplan.io/reference/
Ping still doesn't work but HTTP and HTTPS request to IPv4 servers should work now.
You might need to re-apply changes after server restart. I have this comment in /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml:

This file is generated from information provided by the datasource. Changes to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following: network: {config: disabled}

